# How to use the fact that a pair of functors are adjoint?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory, adjoint-functors

This may be more of a heuristic question but I feel like it should have some concrete answers. I want to understand why a pair of functors being adjoint is useful. How do we use that fact to prove things?

Suppose we have our two functors $F: C \rightarrow D$ and $G: D \rightarrow C$ with $F \dashv G$ with a bijection,
$$
\Psi_{X,Y}: \hom_{D}(F(X), Y) \longrightarrow \hom_{C}(X, G(Y))
$$
natural in all the variables. We can obviously use this to get a morphism $\Psi(\phi): X \rightarrow G(Y)$ given $\phi$, but what meaningful things can we say about the map $\Psi(\phi)$ that make the notion useful for proving things.

To take a more explicit example, say $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a morphism of nice schemes. We have an adjunction $f^* \dashv f_*$ between categories of sheaves of modules. So how is this used? Often in algebraic geometry we do have situations where we have a morphism into a direct image of sheaves and want to prove something about a morphism out of the inverse image. But I can never see how to say anything more than "such a morphism exists". Can anyone gives some concrete examples?

Comment: Among the consequences of an adjunction (with notation as in the question) are (1) a natural transformation $\eta:I_C\to G\circ F$ (the unit of the adjunction), (2) another natural transformation $\varepsilon:F\circ G\to I_D$ (the counit), (3) $D$ preserves limits, and (4) $F$ preserves colimits.

Answer (score 2):

In my limited experience by far the most useful thing about adjoints is the fact that *left adjoints preserve colimits* and in particular that *left adjoints are right exact*.

One example where this is useful is having a quick argument for the fact that for a quasicoherent $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module $M$ $f^{*} M$ is a quasicoherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module, as quasicoherent can be defined by having locally a rightexact sequence of the form
$$\bigoplus_I \mathcal{O}_U \rightarrow \bigoplus_J \mathcal{O}_U \rightarrow M \vert_U \rightarrow 0$$

Similarly the fact that $-\otimes_A B$ sends a free $A$-module to a free $B$-module is a consequence of the tensor-hom adjunction.

I hope this explains a bit, why having adjoints can be useful. Sadly I don’t have an example, where the isomorphism $\psi$ is used explicitly. Sometimes you can translate commuting diagrams involving the left adjoint to commuting diagrams involving the right adjoint by using the naturality of the isomorphism $\psi$. However this is often a kind of Yoga and sadly I don’t have a specific example at hand...